# Responsive font size for user input from HTML editor

Tags: html, css, fonts

I have a HTML editor which is used by users to enter some input. There they can also change the font size. So now the HTML which is generated is something like -

`<span style="font-size: 10pt">Sample Text</span>`

I have to display this across all devices. How can I make this responsive?

I can change the font size option from `pt` to anything else. I know about `vw` etc but the problem is that it is not supported by older browsers and some mobile browsers.

Comment: You have not defined what you mean by “responsive font size”. If it means setting font size relative to viewport width or device display width, you need to say that and specify exactly how it should relate. Then show your best effort so far (HTML and CSS and JavaScript) and describe what problems you have with it.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to change the unit of measurement to [**`em`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length) then target specific device types using media queries, changing the relative font size on the parent for each.

> (em) represents the calculated font-size of the element. If used on
>   the font-size property itself, it represents the inherited font-size
>   of the element. This unit is often used to create scalable layouts.

For example, say your HTML editor outputs e.g.

```
<div id="HTML_Editor">
    <span style="font-size: 10pt">Sample Text</span>
</div>
```

Change this to output e.g.:

```
<div id="HTML_Editor">
    <span style="font-size: 1em">Sample Text</span>
</div>
```

Then use media queries to establish the `em` measurement on different devices by setting the base font size on the `HTML_Editor` element, e.g. (using [**Bootstrap's device definitions**](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries)):

```
/* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) { 
   #HTML_Editor{
      font-size: 10px;
   }
}

/* Medium devices (desktops, 992px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-md-min)  { 
   #HTML_Editor{
      font-size: 15px;
   }
}

/* Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-lg-min)  { 
   #HTML_Editor{
      font-size: 20px;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use in your css media max-width and change your font's size depending on the screen's width.
For example:

```
@media (max-width:560px){
    #HTML_Editor span{
        font-size: 8px
    }
}
```

It's just an example. You can fit it in your needs.